# HTML5 video video playlist

Tags: html, video, playlist

this is simplistic, simplified HTML5 video playlist.
Surprisingly for me, it seems to be working just fine in mozzila / chrome / opera just like that
i mean - with ogv ONLY specified in the script.

1. Question - do i have to specify mp4 and webm as well ?
2. if so - how in this particular case ?
3. What about the IE ?

regards

the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>HTML5_video</title>
   <script>
   var videoPlayer;
   var video_count = 1;
   window.onload = function (){ 
   videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo");
   videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", function (){
   video_count++;
   if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
   var nextVideo = video_count+".ogv";
   videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
   }, false);
   }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<video id="homevideo" width="640" height="360" autoplay autobuffer src="1.ogv"></video>          

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am leaving a coment, because this is not an answer to your question, but rather a suggestion on improving the code.  I actually used your code as a base for player I was writing for a client's event.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox, Chrome, and Opera [support ogv](http://caniuse.com/ogv) and [webm](http://caniuse.com/webm) (in the desktop version); webm has better quality than ogv with about the same browser support so that is usually a better choice.  If you want to support IE, Safari, and mobile then you will also need an [mp4](http://caniuse.com/mpeg4) version of your video.  There is not one format that will work on all browsers but if you have both webm (or ogv) and mp4 then at least one of them should work in any modern browser that supports HTML5 video.

You can either use multiple `<source>` tags inside of the `<video>` tag to list the two versions of the video and let the browser choose which one to use, or use `canPlayType()` [to determine](http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/detect-if-browser-can-play-html5-media-format-with-javascript/) whether the browser supports a particular video format, e.g. `videoPlayer.canPlayType('video/mp4')`, and then insert the first format that you have that the browser can play.

If you want to support old browsers that do not support HTML5 video at all (IE8 and earlier), then you may want a Flash video player fallback to use in that case.  Flash video players can use the same `mp4` video that is used for IE9/10, Safari, and mobile.